# How to attach the file url?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to send image **which url im getting from web**:

```
var now = new Date();
if (now.getDay() == 3 && now.getUTCHours() == 20) {
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idaspin/DiscordAmITojpsBot/master/api/brawl_lnk.txt`,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'nodejs request',
            'X-Key': "9qpRc8M55pFb8qDN94jH"
        }
    }
    client.channels.get("447351755043373056").send("", {
        file: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idaspin/DiscordAmITojpsBot/master/api/brawl.png" 
    }).then(() => {
        request(options, (error, response, body) => { // body equals "http://.../brawl.png" here
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                client.channels.get("447351755043373056").send(`This weeks's brawl is`, {
                    file: `${body}`
                }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
            }
        })
    });
}
```

But it (file: `${body}`) does'not send anything. When im putting string with url into file variable:

```
    file: `https://something.../brawl.png`
```

It works.
As error Im getting this message:

> { DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
>       at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\aspan\Documents\AmITojps\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:71:65)
>       at then (C:\Users\aspan\Documents\AmITojps\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>     name: 'DiscordAPIError',
>     message: 'Cannot send an empty message',
>     path: '/api/v7/channels/447351755043373056/messages',
>     code: 50006 }

Answer (score 0):

**Try making it a new Discord attachment.**

```
<channel>.send(new Discord.Attachment("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idaspin/DiscordAmITojpsBot/master/api/brawl.png"));
```

[Example of it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyJ8D.png)

Comment: request(options, (error, response, body) => {
     client.channels.get("447351755043373056").send(`This weeks's brawl is`, {
      file: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idaspin/DiscordAmITojpsBot/master/api/brawl.png`
     });
    })
 
This code works too, but im trying to put ${body} variable. Here is my result:
[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/fkuGjo)

Comment: Discord can't take raw JSON/XML files, try console.log(body) and see if it is a JSON/XML object, if so then get the wanted data out of it and send that. Sorry that I misinterpreted your original question.

Comment: body equals "http://..../brawl.jpg" [screenshot](https://ibb.co/gtVdx8)